# pandas: create a left join and add rows

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I would like to join two Datafame together

```
left = DataFrame({'Title': ['Paris Match', 'Lancome', 'Channel'],
                   'City': ['Paris', 'Milan', 'Montpellier']})


right = DataFrame({'Title': ['Lulu', 'Channel', 'Balance', 'Paris Match', 'Shaq', 'And 1'],
                  'City': ['New york', 'Valparaiso' ,'Montreal', 'Paris', 'Los Angeles', 'Brooklyn'],
                  'Price':[10,20,30,40,50,60]})
```

[image]
[image]

and the result expected is:

```
r =  DataFrame({'Title': ['Paris Match', 'Lancome', 'Channel','Lulu', 'Balance', 'Shaq', 'And 1'],
                   'City': ['Paris', 'Milan', 'Montpellier', 'Montreal', 'Paris', 'Los Angeles', 'Brooklyn'],
               'Price':[40,'NaN',30,40,50,60,'Nan']})

r[['Title', 'City', 'Price']]
```

[image]

I'm doing `result = left.join(right)` and I'm getting an `columns overlap` error on `Title and City`

Comment: I don't understand your desired output.  Where did Lulu-Montreal come from, for example?

Comment: Indeed your result df doesn't make sense are you sure don't just want an outer merge like my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform an outer [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging):

```
In [30]:

left.merge(right, how='outer')
Out[30]:
          City        Title  Price
0        Paris  Paris Match     40
1        Milan      Lancome    NaN
2  Montpellier      Channel    NaN
3     New york         Lulu     10
4   Valparaiso      Channel     20
5     Montreal      Balance     30
6  Los Angeles         Shaq     50
7     Brooklyn        And 1     60
```